# Telerik controls performance issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I just started (minutes ago) using Telerik controls and tried a simple menu just to see how it works. I created a simple menu of 3 items and 1 subitem without any logic behind it, just plain text.

Here's the code for the menu:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Menu().Name("menu")
        .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("esmaga")
                .Items(
                children =>
                {
                    children.Add().Text("item 1");
                    children.Add().Text("item 2");
                    children.Add().Text("item 3")
                    .Items(innerChildren =>
                           {
                               innerChildren.Add().Text("subitem 1");
                           });

                });
        }
        ))
```

Here's the page on the browser:

[image]

The menu is really simple and I can see it on my almost empty page. My page doesn't take 1 second to load but when I add the Telerik menu the page takes 5 times longer to load.

I believe this isn't normal behaviour since it's a very simple control. I wonder what will happen when trying a grid with loads of data, for example.

The question is: is this a consequence of using Telerik controls or there's something wrong here? Some step I missed or whatever?

Comment: I tested but it seems to me that delation not longer then 1 sec

Comment: Well, some other thing has to be wrong, not the telerik usage

Answer (score 0):

We have implement almost 3-4 project purely based on Kendo grid and controls.
Performance may decrease from 1 sec to 3-4 sec not 5 minute it may be something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What could it be? I also noticed that on IE11 it takes about 10 secs to load and on Chrome only 4. Still, 4 is a lot for just plain text

Comment: it is because you are referencing css and javascript of kendo. so it will take time to load once.

Comment: You said you implemented 3-4 projects based on Kendo: don't you reference css and javascript of kendo?

Comment: It reference only once in master page. and Kendo controls will be used everywhere in project so some performance is negotiable. If performance is a real concern for you don't go with kendo. We use it because it is user friendly, easy to use and looks awesome.

Comment: Yes, performance is an issue but, you say you use it (grids and whatever) and get a performance break of 1 to 4 seconds: I want that performance break when using many controls, like grids with data bound all over them, not with a single very simple menu

Comment: see you use 1 control or use 100 control. 3-4 sec will delayled. it doesn't mean it will take 400 sec for 100 controls. Its one time process. I give you demo project download and check your self http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675879/An-Example-to-Use-Kendo-Grid

Comment: I got that, I just don't get why it is delaying 10 seconds to load the control